# grub2-install: error: /boot/efi doesn't look like an EFI partition on a fresh Gentoo install

Tags: linux, partitioning, grub2, gentoo

I need a Gentoo 13 machine to test some software on the platform. I'm not a Gentoo regular, so I'm suffering their install procedures. I'm at 
[Configuring the bootloader | Installing GRUB2](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Bootloader#Installing_GRUB2), and it failed with:

```
# grub2-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub2-install: error: /boot doesn't look like an EFI partition.
```

I backtracked to [Preparing the disks | Default: Using parted to partition the disk](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Disks#Default:_Using_parted_to_partition_the_disk), and it appears I have things setup as instructed:

```
(chroot) Gentoo-2012 / # parted
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) unit mb                                                          
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA VMware Virtual I (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 21475MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End      Size     File system     Name    Flags
 1      1.05MB  3.15MB   2.10MB                   grub    bios_grub
 2      3.15MB  131MB    128MB    ext2            boot    boot, esp
 3      131MB   2572MB   2441MB   linux-swap(v1)  swap    msftdata
 4      2572MB  21474MB  18902MB  ext4            rootfs  msftdata
```

The results above are from the same chapter of the manual, sections [Applying a filesystem to a partition](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Disks#Applying_a_filesystem_to_a_partition) and [Activating the swap partition](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Disks#Activating_the_swap_partition).

I also followed the comment *EFI directory should not be /boot but /boot/efi* from [Bootloader problems and questions](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1031686.html?sid=a3bcc2409e63fe25a0baab32a3e4ce12) on the Gentoo forums, but it resulted in the same error:

```
(chroot) Gentoo-2012 / # mkdir /boot/efi
(chroot) Gentoo-2012 / # grub2-install --target=x86_64-efi --boot-directory=/boot --efi-directory=/boot/efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub2-install: error: /boot/efi doesn't look like an EFI partition.
```

What's the problem and how do I fix it?

---

Here's the corresponding `fdisk` view of the information presented by `gparted` above.

```
(chroot) Gentoo-2012 / # fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 3.3 GiB, 3567640576 bytes, 6968048 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes    

Disk /dev/sda: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 52F5571A-808B-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX

Device       Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048     6143     4096    2M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     6144   255999   249856  122M EFI System
/dev/sda3   256000  5023743  4767744  2.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  5023744 41940991 36917248 17.6G Microsoft basic data
```

---

I also verified the package `sys-boot/grub` supports EFI:

```
(chroot) Gentoo-2012 / # cat /etc/portage/make.conf | grep GRUB
GRUB_PLATFORMS="emu efi-32 efi-64 pc"
```

I then performed an `emerge --ask --newuse sys-boot/grub`, `emerge -pv sys-boot/grub`, and then rebuilt `grub`.

Comment: Try mkdir, then rebooting, and executing `grub2-install --target=x86_64-efi --boot-directory=/boot --efi-directory=/boot/efi`

Comment: @bytec0de - Thanks. If I reboot, then the machine won't boot because it won't have a boot loader. I'd feel much better about the current OS in a state it can proceed. How do I force a re-read of the disk partitions (is that what needs to be done)?

Comment: @bytec0de - I tried the reboot, but it won't reboot. The error message is *"operating system not found"*. Can I ask you... did you know what the problem was, or were you guessing? The best I can tell, two days worth of work is now gone...

Comment: It was an educated guess @jww, which is why I commented.

Comment: If you're here and you used `fdisk` to prepare your partitions on the disk, then it says right in the manual: "grub is going to give you some serious problems if you use fdisk, and you're on your own".  Their solution is to follow the manual's advice and prepare your disks using the `parted` tool, and using that to label your disks using the GPT flags.  Then the `grub-install` won't complain about: "What the partition looks like".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seemed to be mixing and matching BIOS, EFI, MBR, and GPT. I tried to follow the guides and use the GPT, but there were some dependencies that I could not resolve because I am too inexperienced. Its not even clear to me the kernel was built with GPT support (via config option `CONFIG_EFI_PARTITION`).

When I dropped GPT and EFI and switched to purely BIOS and MBR, I was able to boot the resulting machine. BIOS and GPT are supposed to be a valid combination, but I'm wondering if it works in practice (see, for example, [Bootloader Options](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GUID_Partition_Table#Bootloader_Support)).

Here's the configuration I was able to run the machine with:

```
$ parted
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sda
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA VMware Virtual I (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 21.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  135MB   134MB   primary  ext2            boot
 2      135MB   19.5GB  19.3GB  primary  ext4
 3      19.5GB  21.5GB  2012MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
```

Partition 1 is `/boot`, Partition 2 is `/`, and Partition 3 is `swap`.

Comment: You don't even necessarily need GPT for a standard-conforming UEFI, and you were able to mount partitions on a GPT disk. You just didn't have grub's EFI binary successfully registered in your UEFI's NVRAM, as the warnings of `grub2-install` clearly told you. And no matter what the reason is, `--removable` should be able to help you out (unless its sharing a Windows's ESP).

Comment: @TomYan Are you saying that 'error: /boot doesn't look like an EFI partition.' is clearly telling him that he's missing something in NVRAM?  Because I'm having this problem right now on arch linux, and I feel it MIGHT be due to a standard WIn 7 (64-bit) boot partion being NTFS instead of FAT32, but that doesn't really seem possible as I thought it HAD to be FAT of some sort (even though parted seems to say NTFS)

Comment: @ebyrob the error pretty much means you are passing `--efi-directory /boot` while whatever mounted on `/boot` is not a FAT(32) filesystem. If you have an existing Win7 installation, which is most likely not UEFI-bootable, you can either install grub for legacy/BIOS/MBR booting (`--target i386-pc`), or, create a FAT(32) formatted partition yourself as the EFI system partition and install grub for UEFI booting. The caveat of the latter approach is that you can only switch between Windows and Arch with the UEFI boot menu but not grub's. Anyway, you should NOT mount any existing Windows partition.

Comment: @TomYan Win7 x64 boots from an NTFS partition.  Probably hence the confusion on my part.  Installing Ubuntu worked fine (And Debian has worked in the past).  I'm not quite sure how Arch Linux should multi boot with win7...  I know Ubuntu uses UEFI booting, I thought Ubuntu uses GRUB, but perhaps it doesn't.

Comment: @ebyrob It doesn't really have anything to do with distro. You can install different variant (a.k.a. target) of grub for different mode of booting on most UEFI ("native" or legacy). The variant you install determines how you multi-boot (i.e. where/when you select the OS to boot), as you can't change the boot mode once grub is loaded. That's why if you installs UEFI grub, you can only choose to boot your Win7 (which can only be legacy boot) with your UEFI boot menu.

Answer (score 16):

The answer is simple. EFI System Partition (ESP) should be FAT32 (FAT16 or even FAT12 will also do for most proper UEFI; they are mostly shown as `vfat` in Linux) instead of ext2:

```
mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sda2
```

FWIW, if you are not going to install grub i386-pc (for BIOS/CSM boot), you don't need the "BIOS boot" partition. It is only required by grub `i386-pc` (but not grub `x86_64-efi` or `i386-efi`) on GPT.

It doesn't really matter whether you use the ESP for `/boot`. If you do, you should run:

```
grub2-install --efi-directory /boot
```

If you mount it on `/boot/efi` instead, then you should run:

```
grub2-install --efi-directory /boot/efi
```

`--boot-directory /boot` is implied (i.e. default); It doesn't matter whether `/boot` is the ESP, another separate partition, or a directory on the `/` filesystem.

You may not even need to chroot again to perform `grub2-install`; For example, you mounted `sda4`, your partition for `/`, on `/mnt`; AND THEN, mounted `sda2`, your ESP, on `/mnt/boot/efi`, then you can simply run:

```
grub2-install --boot-directory /mnt/boot --efi-directory /mnt/boot/efi
```

Although `grub2-mkconfig` needs to be run in chroot AFAIK. But if you plan on writing a simple and clean `grub.cfg` yourself instead (which is the only graceful way to use grub2), then this will be out of your concern.

Comment: Thanks Tom. It looks like their manual is pretty much broken in this area. Let me try some of these things and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks again Tom. I performed the `mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sda2`. I mounted things again as per the manual, and I was able to run `grub2-install --target=x86_64-efi --boot-directory=/boot --efi-directory=/boot/efi/` with some warnings. `grub2-install` completed with *"Installation finished. No error reported."* However, it does not boot, and produces an error *"operating system not found"*. No wonder these guys don't produce a LiveCD that performs an installation. Based on their instructions, it can't be done.

Comment: As per the manual? What does that mean? Tell the `mount` commands you ran IN ORDER. Also considering the params you used, have you chrooted? Usually you can't really ignore "warnings" from `grub2-install`, so please show what exactly they are.

Comment: Thanks again Tom. Sorry about that; I thought you were familiar with the procedures. The disks were mounted according to [Preparing the disks | Mounting](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Disks#Mounting). Chroot was entered according to [Installing the Gentoo base system | Mounting the necessary filesystems](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Base#Mounting_the_necessary_filesystems). I had to Chroot because I got an error without it. The error was *"grub2-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh doesn't exist."*

Comment: It's not about the "procedures" or whether I am familiar with them. It's HOW YOU mounted YOUR devices. So did you `mount /dev/sda4 /mnt/gentoo; mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/gentoo/boot/efi` in this ORDER and chroot to `/mnt/gentoo`? Again, what were the warnings you mentioned?

Comment: It's not totally surprising that you can't do it outside chroot. I guess gentoo's iso does not have a full set of grub prepared for you.

Comment: Tom, the output from running `grub2-install` was *"Installing for x86_64-efi platform.\n efibootmgr: EFI variables are not supported on this system.\n efibootmgr: EFI variables are not supported on this system.\n Installation finished. No error reported."* The one message was reported twice, and I added the *"\n"* to show where the line breaks were.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37040/discussion-between-tom-yan-and-jww).

Answer (score 3):

I just had this issue and found that /boot existed but didn't have my boot partition mounted to it. Just had to mount the boot partition to fix this

```
mnt /dev/sda1 /boot
```

Comment: Thanks, I almost deleted my `/boot` part for no reason!

Answer (score 2):

If you are installing this on virtual-box make sure you have the enabled the option of EFI under the category of Setting/System

Answer (score 0):

**The Error:**

```
$> grub2-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot

Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub2-install: error: /boot doesn't look like an EFI partition.
```

Inspecting the source for grub2, it seems to demand that `/boot` be its own file allocation table (FAT) compliant separate partition, maybe for security reasons, It wasn't this way before.  grub2 has caved to security conditions inflicted by the motherboard.

I'm doing this on a 2020 x86_64 PC desktop and I chose not to create a separate `/dev/sda1` boot partition, on `/dev/sda`, (marked as bootable during the `fdisk /dev/sda` step).

**Solution1:**

Disable any Bios Secure Boot settings in the motherboard's boot startup BIOS/EFI/UEFI utility, and look for any Boot level security settings to disable.  Assuming you don't like security. It may be a setting under `F7` -> `boot` -> `secure boot`.

**Solution2:**

Cave to grub's new security demands, and follow the manual for creating your own separate partition for `/boot` and grub config steps.

The EFI System Partition (ESP) must be a `FAT` filing system variant (sometimes shown as `vfat` on Linux systems). [The official UEFI specification](https://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI%202_5.pdf) denotes `FAT12`, `16`, or `32` filesystems will be recognized by the UEFI firmware, although FAT32 is recommended for the ESP.
Angry noises that optional steps from many moons ago are now required steps.

**Solution 3:**

The `fdisk` tool appears to be depreciated and marked for removal.  The manual says: "You're going to have problems if you use `fdisk`, and you're on your own."  Their solution is to scroll up on the manual and follow the directions on using `parted` to create your partitions, and mark the boot partition with their suggested `bios_grub` flag.  Then tada, automatically grub knows where to look and what to do.